# SQL server management studio 2008 installation

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have installed Microsoft Visual Studio 2008 & Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 my Windows7 machine. I want to install SQL server management studio 2008, when ever I run SQL server management studio 2008 installation setup I am getting exception (you have to install SQL server 2008 ServicePack1).

I have download SQLServer2008 servicepack1 form Microsoft site and try to install but that one also not install in my windows7 machine.

How to install SQL server management studio 2008?

Comment: what error do you get when you attempt to install sql server 2008 sp1?

Answer (score 0):

The exception you mention is attempting to tell you you will need to upgrade to SP1 to be fully compatable with the other software installed.

Complete the installation of SSMS 2008 then install SP1